# Easiest ways to use vars from PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm using google charts and I need to grab data from a PHP file( or php inside of the HTML file? ) to feed data to the chart . So how would I do this , and make sure that I grab the data before drawing the chart . 
I already went though figuring out how to grab data from a Mysql database with PHP

Here's the code I need to put vars in

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Color');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Votees ');
        data.addRows([
          ['Value from Mysql', 3000],
          ['Value2 from Mysql', 13000],

        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Table Name From MySql',
                       'width':600,
                       'height':450};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
      <div id="chart_div"></div> 


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you could give us some more information about how you are implementing these charts I'm sure we'd be able to give you a more specific answer.  Help us to help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no variable as such in HTML - I think what you mean is that you want to be able to use PHP values with the code you use for the Google charts.  I have not had much experience using Goggle charts but [from what I can see](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs) it uses some JavaScript API's.  Perhaps what you are looking for is a way to get your values into JavaScript variables so that you can use them when dealing with your charts plugins.

This is exactly what PHP was made for - taking static static content and embedding scripts  giving it dynamic content.

For example, you could have your PHP initializing a JavaScript variable -

```
<?php
  $some_php_var = 'overflow';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var stack = '<?php echo $some_php_var; ?>';
</script>
```

Now you'll have a JavaScript variable called `stack` and its value will be 'overflow'.

---

The same technique can be used in any place - even in the middle of a variable definition.  Lets take your code as an example -

```
// Set chart options
var options = {
  'title':'<?php echo $dbResult['Table Name'] ?>',
  'width':600,
  'height':450
};
```

...

```
data.addRows([
  ['<?php echo $dbResult['value1']; ?>', 3000],
  ['<?php echo $dbResult['value2']; ?>', 13000],
]);
```

Comment: The OP is using some sort of google charts plugin - I assume that it is implemented using some sort of JavaScript API and that you would feed the data to it.   Generating JavaScript code is different from simply echoing a variable value.

Comment: Not really. Generating data, or javascript, or whatever is just echoing out stuff. I've added a second example to my answer to demonstrate it.

Comment: This method worked, now I just have to run the SOL query in the PHP code above, get the data and assign it to a varible .

Comment: Just let us know if some $dbResult value comes with a single quote (') inside and breaks your generated JS code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You insert values from PHP like this:

```
  <?php echo $myVariableName; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplistic example: in a PHP file, like index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $the_data_as_a_string;
?>
</body>
```

Far better way to do it is to actually open a script tag with type of text/plain and dump the data there.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script id="the-data" type="text/html" ><?php echo $the_data_as_a_string; ?></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var data = document.getElementById('the-data').innerHTML;
</script>
</body>
```

The top script tag will not get executed by the browser, but the bottom one can still access it's contents as a string and do whatever it needs with it.

EDIT:

The advantage is that you can safely write your .js files and include them as static ones, thus they will be cached by the browser.

Also you can include the data script one so even the html is going to be static = not changed every time = cached by browser.

Note, this is just a lazyman's ajax request for the data, which you should consider. :)

Comment: But how would I use that data elsewhere in the html document

Comment: I have never seen this approach before - seems slightly long as opposed to other methods.  Can you give any advantages of your method?  I understand the possible escaping issues with a solution similar to [mine](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/11603372/558021), but these become non-issues if dealt with handled correctly server side...

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html As for other than Google, if they're with ill intent, they will get it the other way also ;)